# JSESSIONID lost on Nginx reverse proxy on jboss

Tags: nginx, jboss, reverse-proxy, jboss5.x, jsessionid

I'm starting to migrate from apache2 to nginx.

I have a jboss application on localhost whick used to be reverse proxyfied by apache2.

My nginx site redirect to jboss by I can't manage to stay connected and I am redirected by jboss to the login page.

I suspect a problem with the jsession but cant manage to get it right ... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a sample of my old apache2 vhost.

```
<VirtualHost thisis.mydomain.fr:80>
         ServerName thisis.mydomain.fr
        Redirect / https://thisis.mydomain.fr
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost thisis.mydomain.fr:443>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mycert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mycert.key
        ServerSignature On
        ProxyVia on
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ServerAdmin myname@mydomain.com
        ServerName thisis.mydomain.fr
        ServerAlias http://thisis.mydomain.fr
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp-webctx/ timeout=3600
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp-webctx/
        ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /myapp-webctx /

        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My attempt at converting it to a nginx vhost is like this : 
**/etc/nginx/proxy.conf**

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size    10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffers           32 4k;
proxy_headers_hash_max_size 1024;
proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;

# Enable GZip compression
gzip                on;
gzip_http_version   1.1;
gzip_min_length     1000;
gzip_buffers        16 8k;
gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6] \.";
gzip_types          text/html text/css text/xml application/x-javascript application/atom+xml text/plain
gzip_vary           on;
```

**myvhost.conf**

```
server {
    listen   80;

    server_name my.domain.fr;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# the nginx server instance
server {
    listen   443 ;

    server_name my.domain.fr myapp;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.log;

    ssl_certificate        /etc/nginx/ssl/myapp.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/myapp.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;


    location / {
      proxy_cookie_path  /myapp-ctx/ / ;
      proxy_cookie_path  / /myapp-ctx ;
      proxy_cookie_domain 127.0.0.1 my.domain.fr;
      if ($http_cookie ~* "jsessionid=([^;]+)(?:;|$)") {
        set $co "jsessionid=$1i; Path=/";
      }
      proxy_set_header Cookie "$co";
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_redirect  / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp-ctx/;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp-ctx/;
    }

 }
```

Regards

Tony